# How to remove all file extensions in bash?

Tags: bash, substitution, file-extension

```
x=./gandalf.tar.gz
noext=${x%.*}
echo $noext
```

This prints `./gandalf.tar`, but I need just `./gandalf`.
I might have even files like `./gandalf.tar.a.b.c` which have many more extensions.

I just need the part before the first `.`

Comment: @anubhava I suggested the same in a now deleted comment. Note the `.` at  the beginning of `$x`.

Comment: @anubhava: This prints an empty line.

Comment: `x=./gandalf.tar.gz; echo "${x//.tar.gz/}"` bash parameter expansion replace the file extension with empty string.

Comment: _I just need the part before the first ._ The **first** period is the period before the slash. You want to have the part before the first . after the last slash, and this is what it makes things tricky.

Comment: `[[ "$x" =~ (./[^.]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`?

Comment: Why is there `./`? Is this output of `find`?

Comment: I assumed that the path can be generic (or missing at all) in my regexp answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to give `sed` a chance then:

```bash
x='./gandalf.tar.a.b.c'
sed -E 's~(.)\..*~\1~g' <<< "$x"

./gandalf
```

Or 2 step process in bash:

```bash
x="${s#./}"
echo "./${x%%.*}"

./gandalf
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `extglob` shell option of `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
x=./gandalf.tar.a.b.c
noext=${x%%.*([!/])}
echo "$noext"
```

This deletes the substring not containing a `/` character, after and including the first `.` character. Also works for `x=/pq.12/r/gandalf.tar.a.b.c`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a regexp is the best way to go if your bash version supports it, as it doesn't fork new processes.

This regexp works with **any** prefix path and takes into account files with a dot as first char in the name (hidden files):

```bash
[[ "$x" =~ ^(.*/|)(.[^.]*).*$ ]] && \
noext="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

#### Regexp explained

The first group captures everything up to the last `/` included (regexp are greedy in bash), or nothing if there are no `/` in the string.
Then the second group captures everything up to the first `.`, excluded.

The rest of the string is not captured, as we want to get rid of it.

Finally, we concatenate the path and the stripped name.

#### Note

It's not clear what you want to do with files beginning with a `.` (*hidden files*). I modified the regexp to preserve that `.` if present, as it seemed the most reasonable thing to do. E.g.

```
x="/foo/bar/.myinitfile.sh"
```

becomes `/foo/bar/.myinitfile`.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, for instance something like this:

```
fil=$(basename "$x")
noext="$(dirname "$x")"/${fil%%.*}
```